# jquery adding a css class on a specific page

Tags: jquery, html, css

My main aim is add an active class, to a unordered li. This is based on the a specific page the user is based on. Basically a conditional format. I hope to create a responsive design but I am currently learning jQuery on MAMP.

Current slow way...

HTML

```
<nav id="main-site-nav" class="main-menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.php" class="crnt-page">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/services.php">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="/certification.php" >Certification</a></li>
  <li><a href="/customers.php">Customers</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact-me.php">Contact Me</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#main-site-nav .crnt-page {
 color: #E8A317;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

I am having to add the class for every li. I wish to do this in my main.js at the bottom of the page. Any help would be grateful.

---

UPDATE!

This was the final PHP solution. Although I am tempted to port this across to Wordpress.

```
<nav id="main-site-nav" class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="crnt-page"';?>href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'services.php')) echo 'class="crnt-page"';?>href="/services.php">Services</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'certification.php')) echo 'class="crnt-page"';?>href="/certification.php">Certification</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'customers.php')) echo 'class="crnt-page"';?>href="/customers.php">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'contact-me.php')) echo 'class="crnt-page"';?>href="/contact-me.php">Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks for the quick responses! Now I just have to get used to this pre-formatted code option in stack overflow :)

Comment: This may be what you're looking for but it's a PHP method rather than javascript (so will be better as it work in non-js browsers): http://blog.elanman.com/2009/01/highlight-current-page-using-php-includes/

Comment: Don't quite understand your problem. Can you be more detailed?

Comment: Try not to get into the buzzword limbo - responsive design has [almost] nothing to do with jQuery, which has definitely nothing to do with your server environment [MAMP].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using PHP.

Here is the PHP idea,

```
<nav id="main-site-nav" class="main-menu">
 <ul>
  <li <?php if($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == 'index.php') echo 'class="crnt-page"'; ?>><a href="index.php" class="crnt-page">Home</a></li>
  <li <?php if($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == 'services.php') echo 'class="crnt-page"'; ?>><a href="/services.php">Services</a></li>
  <li <?php if($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == 'certification.php') echo 'class="crnt-page"'; ?>><a href="/certification.php" >Certification</a></li>
  <li <?php if($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == 'customers.php') echo 'class="crnt-page"'; ?>><a href="/customers.php">Customers</a></li>
  <li <?php if($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == 'contact-me.php') echo 'class="crnt-page"'; ?>><a href="/contact-me.php">Contact Me</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I took it copy and made changes it worked!

<li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="crnt-page"';?>href="index.php">Home</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like the following (though untested):

```
var currentPage = document.location.href.split('/').pop().toLowerCase();

$('#main-site-nav a').filter(
    function(){
        return currentPage == this.href.split('/').pop().toLowerCase();
    }).addClass('crnt-page');
```

Though this would be much easier to do server-side (while the server is generating the page).

References:

- [`addClass() (jQuery method)](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`filter()` (jQuery method)](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to add a class to the body on each page, like this:

```
<body class="services">
```

Then in the list add classes to either li's or a's like this:

```
<li class="services"><a href="..."></a></li>
<li class="certification"><a href="..."></a></li>
```

And in your script just do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bodyClass = $("body").attr("class");
    $("li."+bodyClass).find("a").addClass("crnt-page");
});
```

This can be done in a number of ways, not necessarily this way (especially if you already have classes on your body), but the general idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<style>.green {background-color: green;}</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="bla.html">bla</a></li>
    <li><a href="test2.html">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="pfff.html">pff</a></li>
    <li><a href="bar.html">foo</a></li>
  </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var url = /\/([^\/]+)$/.exec(document.location.href)[1];
  $('a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('green');
</script>
```